# Can an attribute of an class instance be cast to a different type?

Tags: c++

Have a basic C++ Question:

Is it possible to cast an attribute of a class instance to a different type?

Haven't used C++ for a long time, but I imagine this should be doable since casting is just telling the compiler to interpret the binary data differently?

Comment: "Property" is not a C++ word.

Comment: This question doesn't make sense in its current form. Maybe you should add some demo code to illustrate what you are trying to do.

Comment: Casting is extremely similar to how it works in Java.  Have you tried something and you're getting an error?

Comment: "An attribute of a class instance"? What is an attribute of a class instance? And no, casting is NOT "telling the compiler to interpret the binary data differently". Casting performs *conversion*, which is fundamentally different from raw *reinterpretation* of binary data. Casting can be used for reinterpretation, but by itself it is not reinterpretation.

Comment: In C++ classes do not have attributes. You might mean "member variable"? Regardless, casting is something you do to a *value* not to a variable. Casting is not just telling the compiler to interpret binary data differently. Reinterpret cast does that but static cast generally does not. Try casting a small int to an unsigned int some time, you'll notice that you often get the same numeric value resulting ...

Comment: Not that clear what you're trying to ask.